# Aligning sub menu to right using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have the html code

```
<div id="menu">
<ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Product Info</span></a>
        <div class="columns two">
            <ul class="one">
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.3</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.4</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.5</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.6</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.7</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.3</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.4</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.5</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Item 2.6</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in this case all the sub menus will be displayed one below another. i want the jquery code so that i can align the sub menu such a way that it will be aligned to the right if the sub menu items are more than 3. for example if i have 6 sub menus, first 3 should be in the first column, next 3 in the next column and so on.. please help me with the code

Comment: and your jquery tried?????

Comment: i just copied the code from http://apycom.com/menus/16-yellow-green.html . i want the same feature. but it should automatically get aligned when number of sub menu increases..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the following lines of code in tour `jquery` to get the required output

```
if($('.one').children().length>3){
    $('.one li').css('float','left');
    $('.one li:nth-child(3n+1)').css('clear','both');
}
```

Comment: i had put the code like this inside the head. but not working.      <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 if($('.one').children().length>3){
    $('.one li').css('float','left');
    $('.one li:nth-child(3n+1)').css('clear','both');
}
 });
</script>                                                        please assist

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 if($('.one').children().length>3){
 $('.one li').css('float','left');
 $('.one li:nth-child(3n+1)').css('clear','both');
 }
```

within load function,

```
    $(window).load(function () {
   // Your function....
    });
```

or

```
    $(document).load(function () {
   // Your function....
    });
```